# Selenium can't find element

Tags: python, selenium, xpath

I am having trouble accessing elements:

```
<fieldset>
  <legend>
    Legend1
  </legend>
  <table width=100%" cellspacing="3" bgcolor="white">
    <tbody>
      <tr>...</tr>
      <tr>...</tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
  <fieldset>
    <legend>
      Legend2
    </legend>
    <table width="100%" cellspacing="3" bgcolor="white" align="center">
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td></td>
          <td class="reportLabel" nowrap="">Label1</td>
          <td class="reportField>Field1</td>
          <td></td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
    <fieldset>
       ...
```

I can access everything in the first table (before entering a sub-fieldset).  However, I can't access anything from the fieldset on.  The error I get is:

```
Message: Unable to find element with xpath == ...
```

Is there something special I have to do when there are new fieldsets?  Similar to having to switch frames?

The command I'm using is:

```
ret = self.driver.find_element_by_xpath("//fieldset/legend[text()='Legend2']/following::table/tbody/tr/td[@class='reportlabel'][text()='Label1']")
```

The reason I'm including the legend and following it with 'following' is that there are a lot of different sections and legends within a previous one, and I'd like to ensure that the field is indeed in the proper section.

I have also tried simpler things, though, such as:

```
ret = self.driver.find_element_by_xpath("//fieldset/table/tbody/tr/td[@class='reportLabel][text()='Label1']")
```

I am using:

```
IE11 (same issue on Firefox, though)
Selenium 2.44.0
Python 2.7
Windows 7
32 bit IEDriverServer.exe
```

Does anyone know why I can't access these elements?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your second `XPATH` looks correct unless the fact that you are missing a `'` after `reportLabel`. Corrected:

```
//fieldset/table/tbody/tr/td[@class='reportLabel'][text()='Label1']
```

**Working `xpath` as per OP's comment**

```
//legend[contains(.,'Legend2')]//..//td[contains(text(),'Label1')]
```

Comment: How about `//legend[contains(.,'Legend2')]//..//td[contains(text(),'Label1')]`?

Comment: that worked! With that being said, though, what is the contains(., 'Legend2') doing?  I know in Unix, a single dot means 'current location'

Comment: ah.  Why would that be necessary, then? I figured selenium knew

Comment: Not sure what you mean but you should be able to do `//td[contains(text(),'Label1')]` as well

Comment: That's not exactly the same. `.` is a string concatenation of all descendant text nodes, `text()` selects only immediate child text nodes. Also, please reduce `//..//` to `/..//`. `.` means "context", not self. `self::` selects the self.

Comment: @MathiasMüller Good to know. Thanks for the correction. I only added `//..//` because OP wanted to do the search based on the `legend`. I also suggested a shorter version of `xpath`  removing the `//..//`

Comment: as much as I love CSS.. i can't stand how you can do something like `..` in it `:(`

Comment: @sircapsalot not to mention. `Css` is my second choice for writing `selenium` test whereas `id` is first