# Python and Selenium: identification of elements in 'tables within tables' without using a keyword

Tags: python, selenium

I want to scrape [this](http://www.cybase.org.au/index.php?page=card&table=protein&id=85) page with selenium.

The information I want to extract is in two tables'

First, I want all of the information from the 'General Information' table:

```
Name           RTD-1
Sequence       RCICTRGFCRCLCRRGVC
Class          Primate
Average Mass   2081.56
Monoisotopic Mass   2079.91
m/z M+H         2080.92
ProteinType     Wild type
Parent  
Organism        Macaca mulatta (rhesus monkey)
Notes           Theta-defensin.
Cyclic          Yes
```

I can extract this table without difficulty using the following code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
import os
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
import pandas as pd
import time
import sys
import re
import requests

options = Options()
options.binary_location=r'C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe'
options.add_experimental_option('excludeSwitches', ['enable-logging'])
options.add_argument("--headless")
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options,executable_path='/mnt/c/Users/kela/Desktop/selenium/chromedriver.exe')
driver.get('http://www.cybase.org.au/index.php?page=card&table=protein&id=85')

def parse_field(field_str):
       field = driver.find_element_by_xpath(str(field_str))
       if field:
               return(field.text.strip())
       else:
               return('-')


field = lambda x: "//tbody/tr/td[contains(.,'" + x + "')]/following::td[1]"
field_list = ['Name','Sequence','Class','Average Mass','Monoisotopic Mass','m/z M+H','ProteinType','Parent','Organism','Notes','Cyclic']
for i in field_list:
        text_to_return = parse_field(field(i))
        print(text_to_return)
```

For the table with the legend of 'Assay', I want to extract ONLY the name of the assay (i.e. in this case, anti-bacterial and membrane-binding assay) and the UID of the paper, which is embedded in a href (it is called uid_list).

Code like this that I found from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28813670/selenium-cant-find-element) (and variations of this code) sort of work:

```
assay = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//legend[contains(.,'Assay')]//..//td[contains(text(),'.')]/following::td[1]").text
```

In this case, 'Tang YQ et al. (1999) Science 286:498-502' is printed.

I have tried other variations of this line, e.g if I change to:

```
assay = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//legend[contains(.,'Assay')]//..//td[contains(text(),'Anti-bacterial')]/following::td[1]").text
```

The output is:

```
RTD-1-3 shown to possess anti-bacterial activity [...] Tran D et al. (2002) J Biol Chem 277:3079-84
RTD-1 found to possess anti-microbial activity greater than the acyclic analogue. [...] Tang YQ et al. (1999) Science 286:498-502
```

You can see that the particular table that I want appears to be tables within tables:

[image]

How do I tweak this line of code to just return:

```
Antibacterial     ...and the set of 'list_UIDs' (i.e. the number in the href) for these rows
Membrane-binding assay   ...and the set of 'list_UIDs' (i.e. the number in the href) for these rows.
```

There is one important note, the assay names (i.e. antibacterial, and membrane binding assay) do not remain constant between pages. e.g. a different page might have completely different assay names. This is where I am stuck, how to return the assays and UIDs, without identifying the text by a particular word (e.g. anti-bacterial).

Edit 1: based on suggestion below, I tried this:

```
##second box
assaynames = []
assays = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector("#main > fieldset:nth-child(4) > table > tbody > tr > td > table > tbody > tr > td")
i = 0
for assay in assays:
        if i==0 or i%2==0:
                assaynames.append(assay.text)
                i+=1


print(assaynames)
```

The output being:

```
RTD-1
RCICTRGFCRCLCRRGVC
Primate
2081.56
2079.91
2080.92
Wild type

Macaca mulatta (rhesus monkey)
Theta-defensin.
Yes
['Anti-bacterial']
```

I'm just wondering how to extract **all** of the assays in the assay box? So i.e. in this case, the information for anti-bacterial and membrane-binding assay? The other part that's missing from the suggestion below is to also extract the PMID reference (see original Q).

Answer (score 0):

Your solution can be like following,

I am getting the table and the elements intervals which return zero with module 2 will be your assay names :

```
assaynames = []
assays = driver.find_elements_css_selector("#main > fieldset:nth-child(4) > table > tbody > tr > td > table > tbody > tr > td") 
i = 0;
    for assay in assays : 
        if i==0 or i%2==0
        assaynames.append(assay.text)
        i+=1
```

Comment: I appreciate it, I've just added to the question above to explain my issue, in this case, it will only print 'anti-bacterial' and not 'membrane-binding' aswell? So (I appreciate it, it's definitely a start), but it won't print all of the assay names in the box? (i.e. antibacterial and membrane-binding assay?)